# xDebug: What's the number included in var_dump?

Tags: php, xdebug, var-dump

If you're using xDebug with PHP and `var_dump` an object, you'll see output something like this

```
object(Example)[176]
```

That is, `var_dump` will show you the variable is an `object`, that its class is `Example`, and -- then there's the number.  In the above example, this number is `176`.  What is this number?  Memory usage? Internal reference count?  Something else?  A cursory look at the documentation and Google hasn't turned anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number is an internal object handle (it's actually a global instance counter, but that's an implementation detail).

Its purpose is to enable the developer to "visually" compare objects for identity; two objects compare equal with `===` if and only if that number is the same on the `var_dump` printout of both.